# Text too long for Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a popover for a div using Twitter Bootstrap, but the text is too long and it seems to exceed the maximum width of the popover.

I want to show ... at the end of the text so I tried to style `<li>` with `text-overflow:ellipsis;`, but that didn't work.

javascript:

```
$(div).popover({
  placement : 'right',
  title : function (){
    return '<span class="title">Title</span>';
  },
  content: function (){
    return '<div class="body"><ul>'
           + '<li>This_is_a_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_text</li>'
            + '</ul></div>'
   },
   container : 'body',
   html : 'true'
 });
```

How can I wrap the text properly?

Comment: Add overflow:hidden to the popover class?

Comment: Using Bootstrap 2 or 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/W6a3B

```
.popover-content, .popover-content .body {
    width: 100%;
}
.popover-content li {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Probably you can make the rule as `.body li` rather than `.popover-content li` so it is more specific to this content.

Comment: Sure. Personal preference, I suppose.

Comment: +1I mean what if i have another popover on the same page and which has some content that has li which is completely different altogether, thats what i meant. But +1 though you nailed it.

Answer (score 3):

My text on the page had the '...' and I wanted the popover to show the full text (which seems more useful than truncating the popover).  To do that just override the popover-content style:

```
.popover-content {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```